# UITableViewController won't do UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

i got a problem on my `UITableViewController` it wont do `UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` orientation. I already set on `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` function allowing the two portrait orientations.

Here's my code on implementing my UITableViewController

```
UITableViewController *controller = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
controller.tableView.delegate = self;
controller.tableView.dataSource = self;
controller.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

thanks

Comment: Have you checked what supported orientations are supported in your .plist file?

Comment: yup, the viewcontroller works perfectly but when i launch the my UITableViewController it only shows UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that your app itself won't support upside-down (the Apple human interface guidelines suggest that iPhone apps should not be rotated upside-down.)  You can modify this in your project settings within Xcode.

[image: Four rotation options within Xcode.]

If that's not it, can you post your code for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`?

Comment: Which is funny because for one, the ITC app sure does.

Comment: @MDT - I can think of about a hundred HIG violations in the ITC app.

Comment: hi aaron i already did this. My viewcontroller works perfectly allows both portait orientation but when i fire my TableViewController it wont do a Upside Down portrait orientation. The thing is i embed my TableViewController in modal inside a navigation.

Comment: @andsien - Can you show the code where you add it?  Are you adding it to your root view controller?  For modal view controllers on iPhone, I recommend adding to the root view controller.

Also, when adding child view controllers are you using the AddChildViewController method, or otherwise passing along rotation events?  It's possible nobody ever tells your table view controller that the user has rotated the device.